# How to let my laragon server to start using http://localhost instead of file:///

Tags: php, laravel, server, laragon

I just downloaded largon as a server for my php projects. Now am finding it hard to let my file be in form of localhost:/test.php instead of file://test.php. When it's using file:// all my code are not executed when run in the browser instead it shows as written in the editor  in the browser.

Can someone guide me on how to switch the file:// to localhost:/

Thanks.

Comment: well, just type localhost:// into your browser?

Comment: I did and it shows laragon welcome page but when creating a new folder for a new project that's the problem.

Comment: then you'll have to add that folder to the url (depending on how virtual server is set up). smth like `localhost://myproject/`

Comment: Did that. Showing access forbidden.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Adetona77: 
If your **www** folder contains a folder name ***adetona*** and a file name ***test.php*** like this:

```
www 
---test.php 
---adetona
```

With Laragon, you can access **test.php** via:
http://localhost/test.php

For folder **adetona**, you have 2 options:

1. Access it via localhost:
   http://localhost/adetona
2. Access via pretty url:
   http://adetona.dev

The option 2 is a powerful feature of Laragon